# how to add list of object to the java object

Tags: java, excel, list, jsp, object

i have the VO class where i am getting the values from the backend in the form of cursor and iterating over the object.so in the dao class i am able to get the values ,so i am setting that values in that class and getting it in the contoller but i am not getting how to display the same value in my jsp page.here i have to show this data in the excel sheet.so row by row i want to print the data which i have uploaded.

```
List<UploadRowVO> UploadRows=new ArrayList<UploadRowVO>();
```

this is the procedure where i am getting details as output.

```
UploadGenJava.getInstance().getProcessDetails(services, fileName, userId,Details,sqlErrMsg);
```

here i am iterating over the result set.

```
for (OracleResultSet rs : Details) {                    
    if (rs.next()) {
        UploadRowVO up= new UploadRowVO();
        up.setPid(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(rs.getString("PID")));
        up.setC3externalComments(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(rs.getString("EXTERNAL_COMMENTS")));
        UploadRows.add(up); //here i am getting error as incompatabile list with UploadRowVO object .       
    }
}
```

anybody help me out where i am wrong..?

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?  The `add()` call you make seems like it should work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,its not working.It giving me this error as java.util.list is not compatible with com.vo.uploadRowVO

Comment: General comment: You should use `List<UploadRowVO> uploadRows` with the variable name in _lower case_ to avoid confusing with class definitions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen..yes that is also ok.but any error other than this..any solution?

Comment: The error message you are getting is inconsistent with the code you have posted.  Please check to make sure that the code above matches with what you had in production when the error occurred.